# How to create custom page number in a TOC in indesign cs6?

Tags: adobe-indesign

My pages in Indesign are somehow complex that they look like:

- A3 - 66

where:

- A: chapter letter
- 3: sub-chapter number (restarts it's numbering everytime the chapter letter changes)
- 66: page number within the chapter and sub-chapter (this means that it restarts the numbering every time a sub-chapter changes)

The problem is that when the TOC is generated the pages will be 1, 2, 3, 4 instead of A3 - 1, A3 - 2, A3 - 3.

Why has been chosen this way of numbering:

- If we update a sub-chapter everywhere in the book we can print the sub-chapter and send to all of the customers and they have their book updated without any kind of inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2):

Under "Numbering and Section Options," you want your Page Numbering to have a Section Prefix (A, or A3, or A3-, for example), and then check the box which says "Include Prefix When Numbering Pages."

So page 66 will show up on the page and in the TOC as A3-66.

Comment: well, we didn't use the prefix, we used 2 variables which are a running-character-style type of variable...